# Successful task generates mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException when trying to commit

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I have a Pig script running in MapReduce mode that's been receiving a persistent error which I've been unable to fix. The script spawns multiple MapReduce applications; after running for several hours one of the applications registers as SUCCEEDED but returns the following diagnostic message:

> We crashed after successfully committing. Recovering.

The step that causes the failure is trying to perform a RANK over a dataset that's around 100GB, split across roughly 1000 mapreduce output files from a previous script. But I've also received the same error for other scripts trying to do a large HASH_JOIN operation.

Digging into the logs, I find the following, which also seems to indicate that the job succeeded but then received an error winding down:

```
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from COMMIT_PENDING to SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP
INFO [ContainerLauncher #6] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: Processing the event EventType: CONTAINER_REMOTE_CLEANUP for container container_e15_1523471594178_0475_01_001013 taskAttempt attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0
INFO [ContainerLauncher #6] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: KILLING attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0
INFO [ContainerLauncher #6] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : my.server.name:45454
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP to SUCCEEDED
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: Task succeeded with attempt attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: task_1523471594178_0475_m_001006 Task Transitioned from RUNNING to SUCCEEDED
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Num completed Tasks: 1011
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: job_1523471594178_0475Job Transitioned from RUNNING to COMMITTING
INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler: Processing the event EventType: JOB_COMMIT
INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Before Scheduling: PendingReds:0 ScheduledMaps:0 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:2 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:1011 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:1011 ContRel:0 HostLocal:1010 RackLocal:1
INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_e15_1523471594178_0475_01_001014
INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_e15_1523471594178_0475_01_001013
INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: After Scheduling: PendingReds:0 ScheduledMaps:0 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:0 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:1011 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:1011 ContRel:0 HostLocal:1010 RackLocal:1
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001007_0: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1523471594178_0475_m_001006_0: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
FATAL [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Error in dispatcher thread
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.checkCounters(Limits.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.incrCounters(Limits.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.addCounter(AbstractCounterGroup.java:78)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.addCounterImpl(AbstractCounterGroup.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.findCounter(AbstractCounterGroup.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.incrAllCounters(AbstractCounterGroup.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.incrAllCounters(AbstractCounters.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.constructFinalFullcounters(JobImpl.java:1766)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.mayBeConstructFinalFullCounters(JobImpl.java:1752)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.createJobFinishedEvent(JobImpl.java:1733)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.logJobHistoryFinishedEvent(JobImpl.java:1092)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$CommitSucceededTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:2064)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$CommitSucceededTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:2060)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$SingleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:999)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1385)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1381)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO [AsyncDispatcher ShutDown handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Exiting, bbye.
```

I've tried several methods of resolving the mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException. I've modified the MapReduce configs in Ambari to set mapreduce.job.counters.max to 20000 (just in an effort to test a resolution to this issue, not with the intent of leaving it there). I also tried starting my Pig script with the line `set mapreduce.job.counters.max 10000;` in an effort to override the max counters. Neither change appears to have any impact; the error still displays a limit of 120.

I'm confused why changing the max counters configuration doesn't seem to be having an impact. Is there some related configuration I could be missing? Or is this error message possibly inaccurate, or a symptom that signifies a different issue?

UPDATE: I've found a number of Apache MapReduce Jira tickets that seem to be related to this issue; it seems like it's an existing bug. I've switched to running my jobs on Tez, which eliminates the issue, but I've experienced major performance problems on Tez so I'm still hoping someone has a workaround for this on the MR engine.

Comment: It looks like there are a number of MapReduce tickets related to this issue, and it may not be resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5856, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5875, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6925

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Ambari but can you try hand-editing mapred-site.xml and adding mapreduce.job.counters.max entry before bringing up the cluster?

Another option is Tez like you already mentioned.
But I'm curious to hear more about

> but I've experienced major performance problems on Tez

since in my org, Tez has been beating mapred in most use cases.  If you can share your problem (as a new question), I'll try to follow up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've looked at a few of the servers in our cluster, and mapred-site.xml is correct on those, but it wouldn't hurt to look at a few more. I'll check that out. I've posted my question about performance problems on Tez here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139192/poor-performance-on-hash-joins-with-pig-on-tez. I'd really appreciate any insight you can offer there, thanks!

Comment: "mapred-site.xml is correct" meaning mapreduce.job.counters.max is set to 10000 ?

Answer (score 0):

This  `<property>` is setting  in `mapred-site.xml`  here is  another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899050/org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-counters-limitexceededexception-too-many-counters)  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140177/more-than-120-counters-in-hadoop)   ,

give you other ways  to try ，but I don't know whether it will works

create `job-local.xml` and set the `<property>`  ，use 
 con.get("mapreduce.job.counters.limit")`  in your project . or   to  con.set("mapreduce.job.counters.limit", "200");

if you have changed  your  setting in your  mapred-site.xml  please check  it works.